# Question about Best practice to safely $_POST sensitive informations

Tags: php, ajax

Hi I am working on order page in a e-commerce website. I have values like name(user’s name), address, pincode, phone number, product name, product total price, coupon discount price, quantity, etc..

Among these, I thought product total price, coupon discount price, and quantity are prone to manipulation from hackers. These are queried from the database and stored inside hidden input field in the html. Also I have ajax functionality that changes the total price depending on the choices of coupon the user applies.

The elements are enclosed within form<> and a submit button is used to submit the informations by method post.

What would be the best practice to handle situations like this?

Comment: The price of a product sounds like something that you should be able to determine server-side without relying on the client to tell you what it is...

Comment: Product price is not filled by the user. Data is queried from the user’s cart

Comment: "*Data is queried from the user’s cart*" You have a fundamental design flaw - the price of a product should never be something that a single user's cart can decide.

Comment: @JinSingh: You may be confusing "filled by the user" with "provided by the client".  Perhaps we've misunderstood, but isn't the whole point of what you're asking based on the idea that the client-side code provides the price information to the server-side code, and you are concerned that a malicious user can edit that information?  If you're now asserting that the user can not edit that information, what are you asking?

Comment: Product price is stored in a table that is solely for products. When the product id from user’s cart and product table is matched, the price of product is displayed in the html. Is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: @JinSingh: No, there is nothing wrong with displaying the price of a product on the web page.  (As a user, I'd be pretty unlikely to make a purchase if the website wouldn't tell me the price.)  But, again, you seem to be straying from the question.  *Displaying* a price to the user is not the same thing as relying on the client to provide the server with the price.  You *should* display the price to the user.  You *should not* rely on the client to provide the price to the server.  The server-side code should calculate the price itself.

Comment: @David: I am asking whether there is any better practice to use than to store such sensitive information inside hidden input fields which are queried from database NOT provided by the clients and send them directly via post method.

Comment: @David: i was replying to the other guy for the previous comment.

Comment: @JinSingh: You can **store** this information in hidden form fields if you like, but don't **rely** on it server-side.  "Sensitive" is a relative term.  The price of a product is not a secret, so it's okay to send this information to the browser.  Information which is secret and shouldn't be known by the user should **not** be sent to the browser.  As for what to do with this information server-side, **do not** rely on it.  You can calculate the price server-side.  **Never** implicitly trust data from the client.  As for comment replies, you can direct them to specific users with `@<username>`

Comment: @David thank you for your comment. Actually i have prices displayed in the html. The hidden input fields of price, quanitity, etc were added additionally to fetch data and send them through post method so that users cant mess with them. I’ll have to figure out how to make server-side calculations without relying on hidden input fields. Thanks

Comment: @JinSingh: *"and send them through post method so that users cant mess with them"* - That was a false assumption.  The user can modify anything they like before sending it to the server.

Comment: @David in general sense, a normal person won’t find and modify hidden inputs. That was my point here

Comment: @David Like you and other person said, i agree its best to calculate such information server side and destroy any chance of manipulations

Comment: `a normal person won’t find and modify hidden inputs`...perhaps not, but there are plenty of people with a working knowledge of websites and html who would know what to look for and could easily exploit a flaw like that. If it's something that can save people money you can be sure it will be discovered pretty quickly!

Answer (score 7):

Post the users’ choices (e.g. product id, quantity, coupon id).

Look up their values, from your database, with server side code and perform the calculations there.

Comment: Sounds good! Although it is a whole lot of work..